# valgrind issue with QDialog specified with qt designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, valgrind, qt-designer

I'm developing a simple prototype with qt creator.

I have used designer in order to design my windows.

Say us that main window has a menu with an option called "Suspend". When this option is selected, it is called the method `MainWindow::on_actionSuspend_triggered()` whose simplified implementation could be resumed as follows:

```
void MainWindow::on_actionSuspend_triggered()
{
  SuspendDialog suspend_dialog(this);
  suspend_dialog.setModal(true);
  auto status = suspend_dialog.exec();
  return;
}
```

The `SuspendDialog` was specified with designer, it is derived from `QDialog` class and it is very simple (three push buttons a combo box and a spin box. This class does not allocate memory.

Now, when I run valgrind inside qtcreator for checking memory usage I get two issues of type `Mismatched free() / delete / delete []`. Some bizarrus is that the two issues refers the same line, which is at the end of destructor of `SuspendDialog` whose implementation is:

```
SuspendDialog::~SuspendDialog()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

And that was automatically generated by qt designer.

My question is: is this a false positive of valgrind or am I doing some wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The task has nothing to do with the most of tags but Qt. I also thought I can fix the text but then decided not to: too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By doing the below you are asking for trouble:

```
SuspendDialog suspend_dialog(this); // wrong! do not pass 'this' here
```

Passing pointer to 'this' in Qt implies that you pass the parent responsible for release of *that* widget. Or, the release will happen twice: first when the object on stack getting destroyed and next when the parent object getting destroyed.

If you execute the dialog with `exec()` you can still allocate the dialog widget on stack but do not pass `this` to it:

```
  SuspendDialog suspend_dialog;
  //
  suspend_dialog.exec(); // exec() only
```

Or you can allocate the dialog widget in the heap and then you can pass `this` to it:

```
  SuspendDialog* pSuspendDialog = new SuspendDialog(this);
  //
  pSuspendDialog->exec(); // or maybe show() depending on task
```

Comment: First of all: thanks for your answer!. I tried with your first way and this causes a crash. Apparently, when the dialog is closed the main window is closed. Maybe is important to note that the application is multi-thread. At the contrary, with the second way (using `new`), that works perfectly and the valgrind issue are not shown more. I'am curious for understanding why the first way does not work. I'am voting your question and I think I will mark it as accepted answer. But I will wait a little while for other responses